# Trying to create a form which generates a variable number of fields based on a list

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am building a web app using Flask and Python which creates a quiz for a user. For each topic, I have a list of questions (of varying number, based on topic) which are strings contained in a list (`question_list`).

I need to create a form that contains/creates a variable amount of `StringFields` based on the relevant `question_list` - with the label for each `StringField` a question in the `question_list`.

I have tried creating a `FieldList` based on a child form, however in order to get that to work I had to pre-define the labels in the child form, which is not ideal (due to the variable number of fields).

I have also tried appending new fields to a static field using 'setattr', but this seems to require pre-defining the number of fields in the form class as well.

This is the `FieldList` solution I tried:

```
question_list = [this is a list of questions]
class aQuestion(Form):  #child form  
    question1 = StringField(question_list[0])
    question2 = StringField(question_list[1])
    question3 = StringField(question_list[2])

class QuestionForm(FlaskForm):
    question = FieldList(FormField(aQuestion))
```

This is the append solution I tried:

```
class QuestionForm(FlaskForm): 
    question = StringField('static field')

record = {'field1':'label1', 'field2':'label2'}

for key, value in record.items():
    setattr(QuestionForm, key, StringField(value))
```

No error messages - but with solution #1, I have to specify all the fields in the child form, along with conditional statements do deal with variable length.

With solution #2, it seems it only outputs two fields (without labels), and does not allow a variable number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited:** I have changed the answer a bit to take your comments into account. And this time I've tested it myself, so it should actually work!

---

Your first approach is closest to the right answer, but you're missing two key components: the child forms contain too much, and you aren't using `append_entry()`.

```
from wtforms.fields import Label

question_list = [this is a list of questions]
class QuestionForm(FlaskForm):  #child form  
    question = StringField()

class AllQuestionsForm(FlaskForm):
    questions = FieldList(FormField(QuestionForm))
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/questions/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def questions():
    form = AllQuestionsForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('answered'))

    for question_str in question_list:
        qfield = form.questions.append_entry().question
        qfield.label = Label(qfield.id, question_str)

    return render_template('questions.html', form=form)
```

Don't forget to include `hidden_tag()` in your Jinja `for` loop for each child form. (The error you were seeing before was because the child form wasn't a FlaskForm, it was just a straight Form. FlaskForm [includes CSRF protection](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.12/csrf.html), so you should use that instead.)

```
{% for q in form.questions %}
    {{ q.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ q.question.label }} {{ q.question() }}
{% endfor %}
{{ form.submit() }}
```

If you want to populate the fields in the child form, you can pass a dictionary to `append_entry()` where the key is the name of the field in the child form and the value is an object of the field's type.

Comment: So to start - really really appreciate you taking the time to provide a very clear and well explained response. This has helped me very much.

Comment: I ran into two problems with the solution proposed : Problem 1 was that I received a jinja2 error  - 'Form object' has no attribute 'hidden_tag'. I solved that by moving the hidden_tag () out of the for loop and placing it above. Problem 2 is that while the form is correctly generating a field for each item in the questions_list, it is not assigning labels to them, and I am not sure why that is the case. I will update this post if I manage to figure that one out!

Comment: I've made several changes to the answer, so it should work for you now.